# If $a,b,c > 0$ satisfy $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$ then $\frac{a}{b+c+3}+\frac{b}{a+c+3}+\frac{c}{a+b+3} \geq \frac{3}{5}$

Tags: inequality

> Given $a,b,c > 0$ satisfying the condition $$a^2+b^2+c^2=3,$$
>   prove that
>   $$\frac{a}{b+c+3}+\frac{b}{a+c+3}+\frac{c}{a+b+3} \geq \frac{3}{5}.$$

Thank you all

Comment: If $a=\sqrt{3}$, $b=c=0$, the inequality is not true.

Comment: @Michael There's a positivity condition.

Comment: @LoveMath: *Please* choose more descriptive, informative titles in the future. Users should be able to understand what you are asking when looking at the front page, or when searching the site.

Comment: @ZachL. Sorry, $a=\sqrt{3-\epsilon}$, $b=c=\sqrt{\epsilon/2}$, pick $\epsilon$ small enough, like $10^{-12}$.  I think the right-hand side should be $\sqrt{1/3}$.

Comment: Lagrange Multipliers?

Comment: @Zev Chonoles: thank you so much. I will learn from experience!

Comment: @Zev Chonoles: I speak English not good! I'm sorry!

Comment: @LoveMath If rhs is $3abc/5$ then it is kinda easy to prove.

Answer (score 2):

The inequality is not TRUE.  For example. $a=\sqrt{2}$, b=1, c=0, then

$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4} + \frac{1}{3+\sqrt{2}} + 0 = 0.3536 + 0.2265 < 0.6$

Comment: it seems to me that $c>0$ is not satisfied here

Answer (score 0):

This can be done automagically using Lagrange multipliers (like most inequalities of this kind...)

Take $f=\frac{a}{b+c+3}+\frac{c}{a+b+3}+\frac{b}{a+c+3}$, $g=a^2+b^2+c^2$, and find the critical points of $f$ subject to the condition that $g=3$. In Mathematica, this can be done as follows:

```
In[15]:= f = a/(b + c + 3) + b/(a + c + 3) + c/(a + b + 3);

In[16]:= g = a^2 + b^2 + c^2;

In[17]:= Solve[Flatten[{g == 3, 
   Table[D[f + q g, v] == 0, {v, {a, b, c}}]}], 
   {a, b, c, q}, Reals]

Out[17]= {{a -> -1, b -> -1, c -> -1, q -> 3/2}, {a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 1, q -> -(3/50)}}
```

This shows that there is one critical point (with positive coordinates) at $(a,b,c)=(1,1,1)$.

All we have left is to check that at this point we have a minimum (or a maximum... :P )

Comment: Thank you! But, Can you prove that inequality?

Comment: @LoveMath, well, no one can, because it is false. The opposite inequality, on the other hand, is true, and that follows from what I wrote (you can solve the system of equations by hand, if you are into that sort of things, of course)

Comment: That inequality is true!! Minimum is $$\frac{3}{5}$$
From website: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=min+a%2F%28b%2Bc%2B3%29%2Bb%2F%28a%2Bc%2B3%29%2Bc%2F%28a%2Bb%2B3%29+with+a%5E2%2Bb%5E2%2Bc%5E2%3D3

Comment: this inequality  is not true.as Michael pointed out. let $b=c=10^{-6}, a=\sqrt{3-2 \times 10^{-12}}$, LHS=0.5773. BTW, walframalpha also said there is no globe minimum. the local minimum is not globe minimum.

Comment: Ya,Mariano is right. so this function has max $\dfrac{3}{5}$, min is $\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{3}}$ if $a,b,c \ge 0$